# Questions about explicitly deleting Python frames

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I found this paragraph in Python's [documentaton](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack):

[image]

I have a few questions:

1. Why does `finally` make destruction deterministic? What's the difference between `try ... finally: del frame` and `del frame` without `finally`?
2. Suppose I have many functions that use frame, and I want to create a decorator to help me avoid having to write `del frame` every time, something like:

   ```py
   def del_frame(f):
     def inner(frame):
       try:
         return f(frame)
       finally:
         del frame

     return inner

   @del_frame
   def function_that_uses_frame(frame):
     ...
   ```

   Does it conform to the requirements of frame destruction despite that I didn't delete the `frame` inside `function_that_uses_frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talked to a core developer. Turns out I misunderstood the documentation.

**The only case that users need to explicitly `del frame` or call `frame.clear()`, is when it caused circular references**. Like in the given example, because `frame` contains the local variable `frame` itself, thus caused a circular reference.

```
def handle_stackframe_without_leak():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        # do something with the frame
    finally:
        del frame
```

If there is no circular reference, and you're just processing a frame object from somewhere else, like

```
def function_that_uses_frame(frame):
  ...
```

There's no need to do anything.